# When I log in, it hangs until crng init done

Tags: debian, systemd, lightdm

When I log in with LightDM on my laptop running Debian Unstable, it recently started to hang for around 2 minutes until `journalctl` shows the message `kernel: random: crng init done`. When I press random keys on my keyboard while it hangs, it logs in faster (around 10 seconds). Before I didn't have this issue, is there any way I can fix it?

Edit: using `linux-image-4.15.0-3-amd64` instead of `linux-image-4.16.0-1-amd64` works, but I don't want to use an older kernel.

Comment: Sounds like something is eating up all of the entropy pool.

Comment: The subject of `systemd-journald` and its (claimed) need for the CSPRNG to be seeded has come up in various discussion fora recently.  See https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-May/040685.html for example.

Comment: `sudo apt install haveged` `sudo systemctl enable haveged`

Comment: This problem seems to be back with Xubuntu 21.04...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<del>Looks like some component of your system blocks while trying to obtain random data from the kernel (i. e. reading from `/dev/urandom` or calling `getrandom()`) due to insufficient entropy (randomness) available.</del>

<del>I do not have a ready explanation for why the problem depends on a particular kernel version, or which component on your system actually blocks, but regardless of the root cause,</del>

Indeed, as pointed out by Bigon in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442956/21885), it appears to be a kernel bug introduced in 4.16:

> This bug is introduced by the "crng_init > 0" to "crng_init > 1"
>   change  in this commit:
>   https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=43838a23a05fbd13e47d750d3dfd77001536dd33
>
> This change inadvertently impacts urandom_read, causing the
>   crng_init==1  state to be treated as uninitialized and causing urandom
>   to block,  despite this state existing *specifically* to support
>   non-cryptographic  needs at boot time:
>   https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/random.c#n1863
>
> Reverting 43838a23a05f ("random: fix crng_ready() test") fixes the bug
>   (tested with 4.16.5-1), but this may cause security concerns 
>   (CVE-2018-1108 is mentioned in 43838a23a05f). I am testing a more 
>   localised fix that should be more palatable to upstream.

(https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897572#82)

...Still, you may try using [`haveged`](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) or [`rng-tools`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/rng-tools/rng-tools.git/) to gather entropy faster.

Comment: It looks like in [Linux 4.16.4](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.16.4) some things related to the CRNG have changed because of CVE-2018-1108. `rng-tools` doesn't work on my laptop, because the Intel Celeron N2840 doesn't support AES-NI and thus doesn't have a built-in TRNG.

Comment: Last upload of `rng-tools` in debian from 2011. You have `rng-tools5` package that has been introduced recently

Comment: @Bigon TBH I do not know anything about packages in Debian; I do not use it. This is general advice, not Debian-specific.

Comment: Confirmed with Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic). Had this problem after installing `dropbear-initramfs` and unlocking my disk remotely with `cryptroot-unlock`. Simply `apt install rng-tools` makes things magically work. Thank you!

Comment: Installing `haveged` worked for me. I have an old Intel Core 2 Duo which doesn't have a True Random Number Generator.

Answer (score 7):

It's a change (bug?) in the kernel, see: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897572

To mitigate that installing `rng-tools5` seems to help. Note that I don't know whether installing this package has an impact or not on strong cryptography key generation

Edit: Apparently updating util-linux 2.32 should fix the issue

Comment: No, util-linux 2.32 does not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

It's a kernel bug that can happen with different kernels.

Running `apt-get install rng-tools` as `su` in the terminal should work.

Comment: Running apt-get install rng-tools as su in the terminal has fixed the problem with my linux box.

Answer (score 6):

## May also happen after deleting the swap partition

Hanging before `kernel: random: crng init done` may also happen after deleting a swap partition.

If a swap partition is deleted, the configuration file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` **should be either completely empty or read `RESUME=`. Delete any UUID number. `RESUME=NONE` is not valid.**

```
$ sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

The initial RAM filesystem requires updating for these changes to take effect:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: thx, this helps !

Answer (score 2):

`rng-tools` only helps if your system has hardware support for random numbers, like intel's "*Secure Key*". This way invented with *Ivy Bridge*. My systems with 1037u processors (based in ivy bridge) do **not** have this hardware support. Therefore `rng-tools` do not help.

On another system here with a sandy bridge i3 processor `rng-tools` do help. The `rngd` service must be started very early in the boot process, in order to fill the entropy queue up. This is the case in the boot sequence with Ubuntu, I don't know if this is true for other distributions, but you can find out, as the start of `rngd` is logged in syslog.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. You could run `rngd -f -r /dev/urandom` to pump `/dev/urandom` into `/dev/random`, though it's advisable not to run it in this manner, it is an option..

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was running a Debian Buster (kernel `4.19.0-4-amd64`) VM on Proxmox VE.

The solution was to add a [VirtIO RNG](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/VirtIORNG) device to the VM. 
On Proxmox, this is done by editing the [VM config file](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Manual:_qm.conf).

In my case, I edited `/etc/pve/qemu-server/110.conf` and added the following line:

```
args: -device virtio-rng-pci
```

No userspace tools (e.g. `rng-tools` or `haveged`) were needed.