# Linux embedded: boot stopped by "crng init" for LOOOOONG time

Tags: linux, startup, embedded, random

I am having heavy problems similar to what discussed in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442698/when-i-log-in-it-hangs-until-crng-init-done).

In my case though, I have a very recent kernel (5.3) for a small embedded processor (mips, mt7628) and boot process stops for *over 6 minutes* till I get the kprint:

```
[  402.804482] random: crng init done
```

after that boot sequence continues normally:

```
[  403.807776] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  403.813440] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Starting kmsgd: OK
Starting applicazione: stream.py OK
...
```

Can someone explain what's going on (and, possibly, a workaround)?

Of course I have no randomization hardware.

Comment: [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=428826f5358c922dc378830a1717b682c0823160) may or may not be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been directed to use [haveged](https://linux.die.net/man/8/haveged) and it actually dramatically shortens startup time:

```
[   12.477886] random: crng init done
```

I will leave this answer for whoever will stumble into the problem.

I will wait for better answers before accepting this.

Note: [this source](https://handyman.dulare.com/long-linux-boot-time-haveged-to-help/) hints there could be some kind of kernel bug responsible for entropy pool exhaustion, but I found no precis references.

Comment: Based on the date in that source, it seems likely it’s referring to the same bug as in that earlier question which you already linked to.

Comment: @Wildcard: My kernel has "#define crng_ready() (likely(crng_init > 1))", but I cannot really believe this "bug" is still there! I am using the very last kernel available (5.3). How can it be?

Comment: Sorry, not a kernel dev even vaguely; I've less idea than you have.  I can probably answer any shell question you'd care to throw at me, though.  ;)

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=43838a23a05fbd13e47d750d3dfd77001536dd33 

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897572#82 

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/58355 

https://wiki.debian.org/BoottimeEntropyStarvation

Comment: To disable long `random crng init` need kernel with CONFIG_RANDOM_TRUST_CPU=y set (or random.trust_cpu=on added to the commandline).